# How to generate code with short type names instead of full type names?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, code-generation, codedom

Assume I want to create a **code file** with a **class** that contains a **field** which has some non-primitive non-aliased **type**. Let it be something well-known: `StreamWriter` type.

I add `System.IO` import to allow short type reference. I create type reference this way:

```
var type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(StreamWriter));
```

But redundant type prefix is still generated:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 2.0.50727.1433
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Bar {
    using System.IO;


    public class Foo {

        private System.IO.StreamWriter baz;

    }
}
```

---

I know I can work around using `string`:

```
var type = new CodeTypeReference("StreamWriter");
// or even
var type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(StreamWriter).Name);
```

But there should be some nice build in CodeDom way, shouldn't it?

---

P.S.: Second workaround may look type-safe enough, but I don't know concrete type, only that it's derived from known base type. So, actually it would look like this:

```
var type = new CodeTypeReference(controlData.Control.GetType().Name);
```

It'll produce ivalid code if the control has some “weird” type like generic or nested type.

Comment: If generating code, why do you care?  CodeDom presumably doesn't know that you will not import two types in the same class with the same short type name, so takes the safe approach.

Comment: I generate very simple View-classes for uGUI. It's possible I'll want to ditch code-generation and add something manually to some view.
Besides, it's just not pretty.

Comment: If you may want to add something manually to some classes, consider generating partial classes.  You can always augment the generated partial class with a manually created partial class.  You still have to decide what goes in the generated vs. manual portions, but it can be quite powerful.  You can use partial methods to create "callbacks" from generated to optionally manually implemented code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: True. Okay, let's forget about manual functionality adding. It's just not pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how [`CodeTypeReference` construction from Type is implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/codedom/CodeTypeReference.cs,7310e583c6dd67d2,references), you'll see that you can implement something like this as workaround:

```
    public static CodeTypeReference CreateShortCodeTypeReference(Type type, CodeNamespaceImportCollection imports)
    {
        var result = new CodeTypeReference(type);

        Shortify(result, type, imports);

        return result;
    }

    private static void Shortify(CodeTypeReference typeReference, Type type, CodeNamespaceImportCollection imports)
    {
        if (typeReference.ArrayRank > 0)
        {
            Shortify(typeReference.ArrayElementType, type, imports);
            return;
        }

        if (type.Namespace != null && imports.Cast<CodeNamespaceImport>()
            .Any(cni => cni.Namespace == type.Namespace))
        {
            var prefix = type.Namespace + '.';

            if (prefix != null)
            {
                var pos = typeReference.BaseType.IndexOf(prefix);
                if (pos == 0)
                {
                    typeReference.BaseType = typeReference.BaseType.Substring(prefix.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### Usage:

```cs
var type = CreateShortCodeTypeReference(foo.GetType(), codeNamespace.Imports);
```

### Result:

Assuming `using UnityEngine.UI;` is present:

- UnityEngine.UI.Button         → Button
- UnityEngine.UI.Button[]       → Button[]
- UnityEngine.UI.Button[][,,][] → Button[][,,][]

### Limitations:

- Won't affect generic type parameters like `List<System.IO.Path>`.
- Valid only for generating code in those CLR-languages that support import (like C# and VB).